# Why did QuickSilver get killed in Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

Why did the directors kill off QuickSilver in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*?

Pointless to have a "main" character killed off after one movie.

Comment: Idk. Hawkeye or Black Widow would have been more plausible.

Answer (score 9):

This is what Marvel producer Kevin Feige said about the death [here](http://www.mtv.com/news/2150560/avengers-age-of-ultron-quicksilver/):

> "It adds stakes to the ending of the film," he said, adding that it also serves as a way "to show repercussions to Ultron's actions, and also in a way to solidify Scarlet Witch's character, and Wanda's arc in the movie and where we'll see her in the next films."

Answer (score -4):

So official answer is that Marvel could only use the two characters, Scarlet Witch and Quick Silver, for one movie, and had to give ONE of them back to Fox.  Since they decided that Scarlet Witch fit into the MCU storyline, so they killed off Quicksilver and gave him a way into the MCU.

Comment: Probably true. Do you have a source though?

Comment: No, cant find source

Comment: I've heard this too (also why Fox never shows Scarlet Witch), but I can't seem to find a proper source.

Comment: If you don't have a source, why did you say that this is the "official" answer?

Comment: [This article](https://screenrant.com/quicksilver-x-men-avengers-2-fox-marvel-dead/2/) **speculates** that it was just to avoid confusion rather than a requirement of the deal.  I also remember reading something at the time about the legal tangle, but this was the best I could find now, so I'm probably misremembering.